# php decrease values in array

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array:

```
Array
(
    [236] => 5.00
    [39] => 5.00
    [19] => 5.00
    [37] => 5.00
    [185] => 5.00
    [235] => 3.00
)
```

For example: I have 20. The total values are 28. Now I want to decrease the values in the array until 20 has subtracted.

so this could be the new array (it doesen't mather from which value it is subtracted). Total value = 8 (28-20)

Array

```
(
    [236] => 0.00
    [39] => 2.00
    [19] => 0.00
    [37] => 0.00
    [185] => 3.00
    [235] => 3.00
)
```

how to do this? When possible i want an option to substract first from the highest value or key number.

Comment: sort array in reverse value order => test sum < 20 => reset first item => rince and repeat

Comment: What is the logic on your final example array? Why would it  have the second value as two and not the last? Or why not the last values be 3 and 5 or 4 and 4 instead of 2,3,3?

Comment: This feels very homework-y lol. Look into [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service... Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: _1/._ if X is the value that you need to substract, check if Array sum is >= to X.  _2/._ Sort your array by [number] desc. _3/._ For each CellValue: a). if CellValue <= X then CellValue=0 and X= X-CellValue b). Else CellValue=CellValue-X and X=0; _4/._ If X=0 Leave the foreach. _5/._ [edit] your implementation of simple algorith in question if you have an issue.

Comment: no it's not homework..it's a pool of users with '..let's say credits..but they share the credits with some people..so when credits are used it must be subtracted from the total of that group

Answer (score 0):

Set your total subtract amount, then iterate your array by reference. Subtract each array value from the total subtract amount, and set that value equal to zero, until you get to a value that's greater than the remaining subtract amount. Then reduce that value by the remaining subtract amount.

```
$subtract_amount = 20;

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    if ($value <= $subtract_amount) {
        $subtract_amount -= $value;
        $value = 0;
    } else {
        $value -= $subtract_amount;
        $subtract_amount = 0;
    }
    if ($amount == 0) break;
}
unset($value); // unset the reference
```

If you want it to work on highest values/keys first, then sort your array accordingly beforehand with `arsort` or `krsort`.